# Is Gradiant Boosting a generalization of Adaboost?

Tags: machine-learning, boosting, adaboost

I read somewhere that Gradiant boosting is a generalization of Adaboost. However, I cannot see why. Can Anyone elaborate?

Comment: AdaBoost can be formulated as gradient boosting with exponential loss. Have a look at chapter 10 of The Elements of
Statistical Learning: https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/ElemStatLearn/

Comment: There's some subtleties to this question.  It could be interpreted in a few ways.  1) Is AdaBoost (mathematically) a special case of Gradient Boosting? (yes).  2) Was gradient boosting discovered as a way to use the AdaBoost model in more general situations (sort of).  3) Is it best to view Gradient Boosting as a generalization of AdaBoost in 2018 (No, it better to think of Gradient Boosting as a primary concept, and AdaBoost as secondary).  Which was your intention (or something else entirely...)?

Comment: My main question is about '1' . If Adaboost is a generalization of Gradiant Boosting and also if using Gradiant Boosting with the right error distribution will yield the same result as adaboost. However, I am not sure what you exactly mean in number '3'. Can you explain a bit?